# Get data in the POST request body Play Framework

Tags: playframework, http-post, body-parser

Play 2.4.x.
How can we get the data that is send through the body of POST request as key value pairs?
I'm sending a post request from the postman plugin, created a key value parit in the body.

How could I get this value from the action function. I tried with request.body() but it could not get the value alone from it..

Is there any way I cloud get the value that is send in the body of post request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [DynamicForm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html) in play's action method.

```
play.data.DynamicForm data = play.data.Form.form().bindFromRequest();

String username = data.get("username");
String password = data.get("password");
```

**Update:**
  From Play 2.5 on wards, inject `play.data.FormFactory` on your controller it allows you to access form. [Reference](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms#Handling-a-form-that-is-not-related-to-a-Model)

```
@Inject play.data.FormFactory formFactory;

play.data.DynamicForm data = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
```

Comment: if I have an array of json data [2,4,5,6,66,45,34] than how do I suppose to write data.get() method in order to have an array of values? Thank you!

Comment: @KyleLuke did you figure it out ?